# Лексикографическое сравнение

Tags: c++, сравнение

```
string s="55", s1="5";

cout<<(s>s1);//true

cout<<("55">"5");//false
```

Почему без создание переменной сравнение неправильно работает?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что выражение `"55"` имеет тип `const char*`, а не `std::string`.

Для сравнения указателей используются правила, отличные от лексикографического сравнения. (Сравниваются адреса памяти, куда они указывают. Т.е. где эти константные строки размещены.) Это поведение сохранено для обеспечения совместимости с C.

Если не хотите создавать сравнить `string` используйте:

```
cout<<("55"s>"5"s); // C++14
cout<<(string("55")>string("5") ); // до C++14
```

Comment: выражение `"55"` имеет тип `char const [3]`